# How to shorten output of 'git pull' command?

Tags: git, github, git-pull

- So I ran `$ git pull` command on a git repository.
- And it outputs useful details that I am interested in, and a lot of other details that I don't care about.
- So is there some switch or option to leave only the details I need?

`$ git pull`

I **need this** information:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 2866, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2866/2866), done.
remote: Total 4840 (delta 2865), reused 2865 (delta 2865), pack-reused 1974
Receiving objects: 100% (4840/4840), 7.51 MiB | 2.98 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3810/3810), completed with 531 local objects.
From https://github.com/erlang/otp
   76da23bb4e..6053c0e4d7  master     -> origin/master
   77cff66931..39968f062e  maint      -> origin/maint
   934f9974eb..f30b1052c7  maint-21   -> origin/maint-21
 * [new tag]               OTP-21.2.6 -> OTP-21.2.6
 * [new tag]               OTP-20.3.2.1 -> OTP-20.3.2.1
Updating 76da23bb4e..6053c0e4d7
```

I **don't need this** information:

```
Fast-forward
 .gitignore                                         |     3 +
 bootstrap/bin/no_dot_erlang.boot                   |   Bin 6539 -> 6541 bytes
 bootstrap/bin/start.boot                           |   Bin 6539 -> 6541 bytes
 bootstrap/bin/start_clean.boot                     |   Bin 6539 -> 6541 bytes
 bootstrap/lib/compiler/ebin/beam_a.beam            |   Bin 3364 -> 3200 bytes
 bootstrap/lib/compiler/ebin/beam_asm.beam          |   Bin 11040 -> 10996 bytes
 bootstrap/lib/compiler/ebin/beam_block.beam        |   Bin 3460 -> 3444 bytes
 bootstrap/lib/compiler/ebin/beam_disasm.beam       |   Bin 20864 -> 20860 bytes
 bootstrap/lib/compiler/ebin/beam_except.beam       |   Bin 4252 -> 4228 bytes
 bootstrap/lib/compiler/ebin/beam_jump.beam         |   Bin 10024 -> 9988 bytes
 .../lib/compiler/ebin/beam_kernel_to_ssa.beam      |   Bin 29484 -> 28880 bytes
 bootstrap/lib/compiler/ebin/beam_peep.beam         |   Bin 3644 -> 3604 bytes
 bootstrap/lib/compiler/ebin/beam_ssa.beam          |   Bin 12208 -> 12176 bytes
 bootstrap/lib/compiler/ebin/beam_ssa_bsm.beam      |   Bin 18176 -> 17952 bytes
 bootstrap/lib/compiler/ebin/beam_ssa_codegen.beam  |   Bin 37824 -> 37708 bytes
 bootstrap/lib/compiler/ebin/beam_ssa_dead.beam     |   Bin 12128 -> 11876 bytes
 bootstrap/lib/compiler/ebin/beam_ssa_lint.beam     |   Bin 7512 -> 7536 bytes
 etc...
```

So how do I do this?

Comment: The first part (which you say you need) is basically the output from the "fetch" part of a `git pull`. So you could get somewhat close to what you want with `git fetch` followed by `git pull >/dev/null`

Comment: have a look at the following configuration parameters: https://technosorcery.net/blog/2011/12/making-git-a-little-less-verbose/

Answer (score 10):

As a reminder, a `git pull` command is in fact a `git fetch` followed by a merge with the given (or resolved) remote-tracking branch.

The first part, useful to you, is the output of the "fetch" part of `git pull`. The second part, which you *don't* want, is the output of the ensuing fast-forward merge.

You could split operations so that you mute only the second part :

```
git fetch
git pull -q
```

Want less typing ? Do an alias

```
git config --global alias.qpull '!git fetch && git pull -q'
```

then just do

```
git qpull origin <someBranch>  # for "quiet pull" for example but anything goes of course
```

Comment: BTW, that would be `git qpull origin <someBranch>`.

Comment: @surendrapanday Wow, this is a misunderstanding, surendrapanday. Yes, I downvoted *one* of your questions, among the tens of upvotes I cast daily. I have no reason to "randomly" downvote people. This is a bold assertion of yours out of bitterness and I'm sorry of it.

Comment: On the question [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54849047/how-do-i-ignore-classpath-in-git-commit), I clearly stated the reasons why I downvoted and any further discussion here on the subject seems out of place... should we not chat about it elsewhere and try to understand each other's point of view? (Anecdotically and finally, would you go on a downvote spree on someone because that person... goes on downvote sprees?)

Answer (score 4):

As [RomainValeri notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54862634/1256452), `git pull` is just `git fetch` plus a second Git command.  It's the second Git command that is "noisy" for you; the `git fetch` prints what you want.

The reason `git merge` is noisy is because `git merge` runs, by default, `git diff --stat` afterwards to compare the previous value of `HEAD`—`HEAD@{1}`—to the current value, after (in this case) printing the `Fast-forward` line and doing a fast-forward operation on the branch name, instead of a merge, followed by a `git checkout` of the updated commit.

[The `git merge` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) takes, among its many other options, these three:

> > **--stat
> > -n
> > --no-stat**
> > Show a diffstat at the end of the merge. The diffstat is also controlled by the configuration option `merge.stat`.
> >     With -n or --no-stat do not show a diffstat at the end of the merge.

Hence, you can split the pull into its separate components (as RomainValeri suggested) and then use `git merge -n`: you'll still get the fast-forward message here, but not the diffstat.

The `git pull` command generally sends most of its options on to `git merge` anyway.  That includes `-n` or `--no-stat`.  Some of its options, it sends on to `git fetch`, and a few it sends to both.  This last is the problem with using `-q` here: it goes to both the underlying fetch *and* the subsequent merge.  This forces you to split up the command into its two components, if you want to use `-q`.

You can also configure `merge.stat` to `false` and not have to deal with any of this.  All your merges will be more silent after that.

I generally recommend splitting `git pull` apart anyway, for multiple reasons.  The most significant one is that often, after `git fetch`, I want to *inspect what I fetched* to decide whether it's time for merge, rebase, or neither.

Comment: I must admit I have inherited this rule from you, and always fetch rather than pull. Thanks especially for the part about pull parameters being differently passed to fetch and merge. I overlooked that entirely.

Comment: Can `--no-stat` also suppress the files that are Auto-merged?

Comment: @alper: all `--no-stat` does is inhibit the running of the (internal, but same effect as a manual one) `git diff --stat` at the end of the merge. Everything else is the same.